# What are some interesting alternatives to line-by-line if/else statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

More and more I realize my code is getting filled with if/else statements. Eventually, I started to write one-liners (`x = 'this' if y > 0 else 'that'`) and, in some cases, if a test were often true, I assumed it was from the beginning and only changed anything if it weren't. For example:

From this

```
def increase_score(self, side)
    if self.player.side == side:
        self.enemy.score += 1
    else:
        self.player.score += 1
```

I would do this

```
def increase_score(self, side)
    # assume player.side is side
    last_enemy_score = self.enemy.score
    self.enemy.score += 1
    # only change if player.side isn't side
    if self.player.side != side:
         self.enemy.score = last_enemy_score
         self.player.score += 1
```

Besides these two approaches, what are some interesting alternatives to line-by-line if/else statements?

Comment: What is the purpose of the second `side` variable?

Comment: You have `self.player.side` and `side`.

Comment: Oh, it's an argument. The code is inside a method called increase_score. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Check out the many answers to the question titled [Replacements for switch statement in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60208/355230).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are overlooking one big logic simplicity. In both cases the player 'wins' if their `player.side` is different to `side`, otherwise the enemy 'wins'.

Why not just use this:

```
if self.player.side == side:
    self.enemy.score += 1
else:
    self.player.score += 1
```

**edit: Clever options below**

Since you are asking for alternatives, here are a few that would also work. Note however, that often simple predictable code is better than clever.

**Casting binary to integers** (only works if you want to add either 0 or 1):

```
self.enemy.score  += int(self.player.side == side)
self.player.score += int(self.player.side != side)
```

**Calling from an array using a binary** (only works with 2 options).

```
winner = [self.player,self.enemy][self.player.side == side]
winner.score += 1
```

**Calling from a dictionary via a tuple** - this would work if you added up and down or wanted some player options to always win.

```
 challenge = { ('left','left')   : self.enemy,
               ('left','right')  : self.player,
               ('right','right') : self.enemy,
               ('right','left')  : self.player }

 winner = challenge[(self.player.side,side)]
 # OR safely assuming the enemy is the defualt winner
 winner = challenge.get((self.player.side,side), self.enemy)
```

Comment: Still, what I want to know is about other ways to implement if/else functionality.

Comment: @Jovito Its hard to answer without some troublesome code. In your case, `if/then/else` works and is consistent with other code.

Comment: @Jovito I stand by the simple option, however I've given you a few more 'clever' solutions. If this helps, feel free to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `dict` to get rid of low-level `if` statements.

```
score = dict(left=0, right=0)
players = dict(left='Jack', right='Jill')

def increase_score(self, side):
    score[side] += 1
```

It is very easy to query the score for any player, and find their current side, and of course incrementing the score is now trivial.

Thinking about this a bit more, how would we handle something like a round-robin tournament, where there are many competitors but fewer games happening at any one time?  Here I would rather key the `score` dict by player name, and then do a lookup inside the function:

```
score = {'Jack':0, 'Jill':0, 'Jane':0}
current_players = dict(left='Jane', right='Jill')

def increase_score(self, side):
    player_name = current_players[side]
    score[player_name] += 1
```

Dictionaries still work really well.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider your second approach dangerous! Noone (including you in two month) will get the logic and understand your code.

Sometimes, logical AND can be your friend:

```
if (self.player.side == 'left')  and (side == 'left'):  self.enemy.score += 1
if (self.player.side == 'left')  and (side == 'right'): self.player.score += 1
if (self.player.side == 'right') and (side == 'left'):  self.player.score += 1
if (self.player.side == 'right') and (side == 'right'): self.enemy.score += 1
```

looks much more tidy and the logic is crystal clear.